# php mysqli insert date to DATE type

Tags: php, mysql, date, mysqli

```
$NOW = new DateTime();
$date = $NOW->format('Y-m-d'); // return 2018-05-17
```

I want to update date in database to now date.

Query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET date = $date WHERE id = $id";
```

But it update time like this => `0000-00-00`

The type of this column is `DATE`

Why? what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try mysql now() function to update date.

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET date = now() WHERE id = $id";
```

Or you should add single qoutes in query

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET date = '".$date."' WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: Is it return in this format? `Y-m-d` ?  look like it return timestamp, right?

Comment: No, it will save date in Y-m-d format, because your mysql column is date type not timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add your date value in quotes then try. Change your query to :

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET date = '$date' WHERE id = $id";
```